# Turning screen off to save power - PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK? android:showOnLockScreen="true"?

Tags: android

I would like to save power by completely turning off the screen (not just setting the brightness to zero), but without the screen locking.

I've tried this with a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK work: It should turn the screen off, but keep the CPU on.

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

Code:

```
private PowerManager.WakeLock screenWakeLock = null;

private void acquireScreenWakeLock() {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    releaseScreenWakeLock();
    screenWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "screenWakeLock");
    screenWakeLock.acquire();
}

private void releaseScreenWakeLock() {
    if (screenWakeLock != null) {
        if(screenWakeLock.isHeld())
            screenWakeLock.release();
        screenWakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

At some point in the code I then run acquireScreenWakeLock(), and let the display time out (say set to 15sec). After say 20 sec, I let the app perform another action, that writes to the screen. This does reactivate the screen, but at this point the screen lock is on.

Am I doing something wrong with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK? Will the screen lock always come on, or is there an option to prevent that? (I've tried setting android:showOnLockScreen="true", but this didn't help with the application being shown.)

Comment: "I would like to save power by completely turning off the screen (not just setting the brightness to zero), but without the screen locking" -- I am not aware that this is supported in Android. "Am I doing something wrong with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK?" -- `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` has nothing to do with the screen. `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` is for keeping the CPU powered on while you are doing work, while the screen is off and locked.

Comment: I guess so - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html  says "If you hold a partial wake lock, the CPU will continue to run, regardless of any display timeouts or the state of the screen and even after the user presses the power button. In all other wake locks, the CPU will run, but the user can still put the device to sleep using the power button." - however, I figured that if the screen is kept unlocked, it might have the desired effect... but as you say it may no be possible!

Comment: A partial wakelock is what apps use to do work in the background (e.g., sync data with a server). If that unlocked the device every time, or if a partial wakelock were capable of blocking the device locking... from a security standpoint, that would be exceptionally bad.